# mouseenter and mouseleave on safari, edge and IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I wrote a js code to trigger mouseenter and mouseleave on map areas.
It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari, Edge, nor IE.

I really can't understand why.

Here is my javascript :

```
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');

// set event listener for all objects
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
    areas[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', inArea);
    areas[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', outArea);
}

// On mouse enter
function inArea() {
    console.log('mouseenter');
}

// On mouse leave
function outArea() {
    console.log('mouseleave');
}
```

You can play with it here : https://codepen.io/fantomette/pen/pVdLwM

What is wrong with this code ? Or maybe you know an other way to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? It produces errors in the developer console? No functionality and no errors? Does it only fail on that `codepen` site, or have you tried it in an actual application where it fails as well?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I don't see the console.log in the console on Safari, Edge and IE. There is no error in console. 
It fails on codepen and on my website.

Answer (score 5):

I replaced "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" by "mouseover" and "mouseout" and it works fine in every browsers.