# onmouse enter and onmouseleave on image map not triggering correctly with IE11 or Edge but works with other Browsers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, onmouseover, imagemap, pointer-events

This is continuation of a previous issue I thought was resolved. It is resolved technically for other browsers so i decided it might be better as a new question with a link to the other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318095/onmouseover-and-onmouseleave-triggering-randomnly-on-image-map).

A link to the Webpage can be viewed [here](https://wordpress-84115-1173103.cloudwaysapps.com/)

So here is the code for my image map:

```
    <div class="tech-interactive-banner">

      <img id="image-map" tooltip="Click Me" src="<?php echo $main_graphic['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $main_graphic['alt']; ?>" usemap="#image-map">

      <map name="image-map" class="image-map-class">
        <area class="automation-map" onmouseover="openAutomation()" onmouseleave="closeAutomation()" coords="304,559,1011,148,1143,229,1518,447,1516,485,1463,497,1444,510,1436,522,1241,636,1159,716,1076,762,959,801,813,884,494,696,304,589" shape="poly"> 
        <area class="integration-map" onmouseover="openIntegration()" onmouseleave="closeIntegration()" coords="1571,477,1456,494,1418,566,1088,756,871,881,868,916,1006,993,1229,1074,1274,1063,1348,1021,1483,944,1629,856,1793,761,1848,732,1881,701,1879,686,1703,551" shape="poly">
      </map>

    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript code. I have enabled comments in the code:

```
  function openAutomation(){
    console.log("openAutomation");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', automation);
    $('#automationModal').modal('show');
  };

  function openIntegration() {
    console.log("openIntegration");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', integration);
    $('#integrationModal').modal('show');
  };


  function closeAutomation(){
    console.log("closeAutomation");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', original);
    $('#automationModal').modal('hide');
  };

  function closeIntegration() {
    console.log("closeIntegration");
    $('#image-map').attr('src', original);
    $('#integrationModal').modal('hide');
  };
```

And again as you may see in the previous issue the thing that seemed to resolve the triggering on onmouseover - onmouseleave - onmouseover was adding `pointer-events: none !important` to the *.modal-backdrop, .modal, .modal-content* classes

If you use say firefox or chrome you can see it function correctly. Basically if you mouseover one part of the image a bootstrap modal pops up and if you mouseleave the same part of the image the bootstrap modal should hide. In IE/EDGE it always triggers the mouseover but when you try and mouseleave it doesn't trigger 99% of the time

Comment: If you use say firefox or chrome you can see it function correctly. Basically if you mouseover one part of the image a bootstrap modal pops up and if you mouseleave the same part of the image the bootstrap modal should hide. In IE/EDGE it always triggers the mouseover but when you try and mouseleave it doesn't trigger 99% of the time.

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is an issue in Edge, but it's an issue in IE, the same `id` and `name` in separate elements are messing the behavior in IE. Give a different `id` to the image.

Comment: This was actually a great suggestion made the transitions a little smoother on firefox. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218322/mouseenter-and-mouseleave-on-safari-edge-and-ie). Thanks Julie. Essentially all I needed to do was replace onmouseleave with onmouseout and it worked perfectly